# Realm arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, realm

Realm issue, didn't change the code at all. Was working fine before, today gives me this error. I don't understand what's happening here. Android 4.4. No error on android 6.0

part of the code where crash is taking

```
        queryDestination = realm.where(Destination.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < queryDestination.findAll().size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chosenIds.size(); j++) {
                if (queryDestination.findAll().get(i).getId().equals(chosenIds.get(j))) {
                    setLabelsAndPacketsCollated(i);

                    generalInvoiceIdsList.remove(queryDestination.findAll().get(i).getDestinationListId());
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    int k = i;
                    realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
                        queryDestination.findAll().get(k).deleteFromRealm();
                        if (!realm.where(Example.class).findAll().isEmpty())
                            realm.where(Example.class).findAll().get(k).deleteFromRealm();  //17.02.17
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Out of range  in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_Collection.cpp line 133(requested: 1 valid: 1)
                                                                        at io.realm.internal.Collection.nativeGetRow(Native Method)
                                                                        at io.realm.internal.Collection.getUncheckedRow(Collection.java:386)
                                                                        at io.realm.OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.get(OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java:106)
                                                                        at io.realm.RealmResults.get(RealmResults.java:53)
                                                                        at ru.startandroid.retrofit.ui.CollateFragment.lambda$onButtonCollateClick$3(CollateFragment.java:231)
                                                                        at ru.startandroid.retrofit.ui.CollateFragment$$Lambda$6.execute(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1325)
                                                                        at ru.startandroid.retrofit.ui.CollateFragment.onButtonCollateClick(CollateFragment.java:228)
                                                                        at ru.startandroid.retrofit.ui.CollateFragment.lambda$onCreateView$0(CollateFragment.java:177)
                                                                        at ru.startandroid.retrofit.ui.CollateFragment$$Lambda$1.onClick(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4881)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19592)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: And magically we should know what happened? Maybe post your code if you want to help..

Comment: please show code for `at ru.startandroid.retrofit.ui.CollateFragment.lambda$onButtonCollateClick$3(CollateFragment.java:231)`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, Thanks for the reply, I've added the part of the code where crash is happening

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"

Comment: Consider replacing `for(int i = 0; ...` with `for(Destination destination : queryDestination.findAll())`, it might fix your problem